# How to test react component with mock api calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I am trying to run tests for one React Component; however, the state of this component is set based on the response getting from an API call.

```
componentDidMount() {
  getStatus().then(status => {
    this.setState({status: status});
  });
}
```

Is there a way to mock this response using Mocha instead of actually hitting the API? Since this is in `componentDidMount()`, I will always get to this block using Enzyme's `shallow` and `mount`, and it throws `fetch is not defined` error

I can get rid of this error by importing `isomorphic-fetch` in my test setup file, but I would prefer to just mock a fake api and make up the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [fetch-mock](http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/#aboutquickstart) to mock `isomorphic-fetch` api calls.

```
var fetchMock = require('fetch-mock');

describe('Test mocking isomorphic-fetch', function() {
  before(function() {
    fetchMock.get('/my/api/endpoint', {hello: 'world'});
  });

  after(function() {
    fetchMock.restore();
  });

  it('should mock fetch', function() {
    // your test code here
  });
});
```